# Efficient struct ordering for less gas

Tags: solidity, struct, state

Unlike initializing state variables in specific orders in order to save on gas, does this also apply to how you declare your struct properties where you keep lower `uint`s side by side each other?

```
// State arranged to save gas
contract Foobar {
    uint8 foo;
    uint8 bar;
    uint16 baz;
    uint num;
}

// Does the same concept apply to a struct as well?
struct Item {
    uint8 foo;
    uint8 bar;
    uint16 baz;
    uint num;
}
```

Or can you go all crazy in the struct and type it in any order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are refering to struct stored in `storage` then yes, the very same rules apply as described in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) :

> - The first item in a storage slot is stored lower-order aligned.
> - Value types use only as many bytes as are necessary to store them.
> - **If a value type does not fit the remaining part of a storage slot, it is stored in the next storage slot.**
> - **Structs and array data always start a new slot and their items are packed tightly according to these rules.**
> - Items following struct or array data always start a new storage slot.

In memory however, every element is stored on 32 bytes, except for `bytes` and `string` as you can see [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory).